# Вызов перегруженного индексатора

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Итак, у меня есть класс-родитель:

```
class Massive
{
public:
    virtual Massive* Clone() = 0;
    virtual int Massive::operator[](int i) = 0;
};
```

(я не стал писать сюда прочие методы типа `Add`, `Delete`, а оставил только нужные)
И дочерний класс односвязный список:

```
class MyList:public Massive
{
public:
    virtual MyList* Clone() override
    {
        MyList *new_mas = new MyList();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            element *temp = last;
            while (temp->index != i)
            {
                temp = temp->prev;
            }
            new_mas->Add(temp->value);
        }
        return new_mas;
    }
    virtual int Massive::operator[](int i) override
    {
        if (count != 0)
        {
            element *temp = last;
            while (temp->index != i)
            {
                temp = temp->prev;
            }
            return temp->value;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error. Massive is empty.\n";
        }
    }
};
```

Так вот, в методе `Clone()` я скопировал код с перегруженного индексатора ибо мне надо найти пройтись по каждому элементу и добавить их в новый объект. Можно ли обойтись без копирования кода, а написать в `Clone()` что-то вроде `new_mas->Add(this[i])`?

Если что, `new_mas->Add(this[i])` не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите вызвать оператор `[]` для `this`, то делается это так:

```
this->operator[](i);
```

Да, а зачем вы везде тянете `Massive::`? Оно внутри класса ни к чему...

Comment: Спасибо! У меня в родителе есть вот это virtual int Massive::operator[](int i) = 0;

Comment: @Harry думаю, `(*this)[i]` было бы лучше.

Comment: @Harry а почему лучше? Одно и тоже ведь, только здесь вы указатель разыменовываете.

Comment: @ Croessmah,  а я разницы не вижу

Comment: @Croessmah Для меня было важно показать, как вообще вызывать операторы - что их можно вызывать как обычные функции с именем вида `operator@`.